# Are there mirrors for chef cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

It's very slow to visit amazon's s3 in China. So, I wonder if there're other mirrors to choose? Or can I build a mirror for chef cookbooks?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a text-only browser like **lynx** helps too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, there are no mirrors for Chef cookbooks.

Comment: The Berkshelf API does not have that functionality

Comment: Do you have the plan to support mirrors? so that other mirrors can be built to support faster visiting for cookbooks.

Comment: I believe there is an open issue on Supermarket about it.